# Efficiently find values from array fitting in from-to range for calculating average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Following problem:
we have dataframe with following structure:

```
... from to   weight ...
    0    50   0
    50   100  0
    100  250  0
    250  5000 0
```

And we have reference list with reference weights(numbers):

`[20, 40, 80, 90, 110, 130, 220, ...]`

Task is: for each row in dataframe try to find weights out of reference list which fit into from-to range (to is excluded), calculate mean and update weight column with mean value

Example result would be a dataframe which contains mean weight values, e.g. in case of weights and ranges above:

```
... from to   weight ...
    0    50   30 (mean of 20 and 40)
    50   100  85 (mean of 80 and 90)
    100  250  150 (mean of 110, 130 and 220)
    ...  ...  ...
```

Taks is really simple, but we are lacking performance with our approach. Update weights on ~200k rows takes about 200s. Main problem is finding row by row all relevant weights which are fitting in range.

Excerpt from our approach:

```
    def __set_mean_weight(self):

        self.input_data['Weight'] = \
            np.where((self.input_data['Weight'] == 0),
                     np.apply_along_axis(self.__calculate_mean, axis=1, arr=self.input_data),
                     self.input_data['Weight'])

    def __calculate_mean(self, x):

        relevant_weights = \
            ref_weights[(ref_weights['Weight'] >= x[self.colIdx_from_kg])
                              & (ref_weights['Weight'] < x[self.colIdx_to_kg])]


        return 0 if relevant_weights.empty else round(relevant_weights['Weight'].mean(), 2)
```

**Update**

Found new approach which runs in approximately 35s. So 6 to 7 times faster, but I guess that one could make this even faster. Any ideas very appreciated.

Here the code:

```
    def __set_mean_weight(self):

        self.input_data['weight'] = np.where(
            self.input_data['weight'] == 0,
            self.input_data.apply(
                lambda x: np.mean(
                    self.__boolean_index(self.weight_data[x['customer']], x['from'], x['to'])
                ), axis=1
            ),
            self.input_data['weight']
        )

    def __boolean_index(self, array, left, right):
        index = (array[:] >= left) & (array[:] < right)

        return array[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

For that, you shouldn't use the apply_along_axis function, instead, make a function for calculating the mean of all customers with weight > 0, and apply that value to all customers with weight = 0.
The way you are doing it now calls the function once for each customer with weight = 0

Comment: But it depends on your from-to-range which weights should be taken for calculating average. Only values of one customer which fit in your from-to-range should be taken into account

Comment: My point is that you're calculating the mean many times, one for each customer with weight = 0, that's what's killing the performance. Try to rewrite the code in a way that you can do it once and store it, then write that value to all customers with weight = 0. Of course you should do it with just the weights that are > 0, but that's another question altogether

Comment: One could not calculate exactly one mean value for one customer, because inside one customer there are many different from-to-ranges. So in the end it could/will happen that for each row we have a different average weight